# Graphical abstract in abstract section of elsevier

Tags: graphics, abstract

I want to add  my graphical abstract after abstract for the elsevier. However, I do not know exactly how could I do that which gives me sth like the photo.[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[1p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[font={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
%\usepackage{subfigure}

% packages for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[skip=1ex, 
            font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
% packages for tables
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}


%\usepackage{nomencl}
%\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{natbib}




%\usepackage[numbers,super]{natbib}
%\setcitestyle{numbers,super}



\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]



%\renewcommand{\thefootnote}
\newcommand\degrees[1]{\ensuremath{#1^\circ}}

\newcommand\mycaption[1]{\caption{\footnotesize{#1}}}

\newcommand\myfootnote[1]{\footnote{\small{#1}}}

\newcommand\scalemath[2]{\scalebox{#1}{\mbox{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #2}}}}


\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\textit}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}


\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage{calc,ragged2e}
\hyphenation{gauss-ian}

\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}




\journal{Eny}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}



\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \title{Implementa of chain fothe case stua} 

        \author[mymainaddress]{Banesh}
        \author[mymainaddress]{Trghfd}
        \author[mysecondaryaddress]{Faeh\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
        \cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
        \ead{s179.edu } 
        \author[mymainaddress]{Sylwska}     

    
    


        
        \address[mymainaddress]{Institute sh Academy of Sciences, Gdańsk, Poland}
        \address[mysecondaryaddress]{Gdanland}
        
        

        

        
        \begin{abstract}


ollowed by hyper-parameter tuning and k-fold cross-validation method. Sugfor the prediction of target variables in similar problems. It is envisioned that the proposed model acts as an accurate and versatile performance evaluation tool that assists researchers in the prediction of energy performance and optimization of various SSs for different engineering purposes.


        \end{abstract}


        
        \begin{keyword}
        Sewage sludge \sep Incintem \sep Energyce \sep Macrning \sep Optimion
        \end{keyword}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the picture emulating the style.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\journal{Eny}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frontmatter}
        
\title{Implementa of chain fothe case stua} 

\author[mymainaddress]{Banesh}
\author[mymainaddress]{Trghfd}
\author[mysecondaryaddress]{Faeh\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{s179.edu } 
\author[mymainaddress]{Sylwska}     
        
\address[mymainaddress]{Institute sh Academy of Sciences, Gdańsk, Poland}
\address[mysecondaryaddress]{Gdanland}
        
\begin{abstract}
Followed by hyper-parameter tuning and k-fold cross-validation method. 
Sugfor the prediction of target variables in similar problems. 
It is envisioned that the proposed model acts as an accurate and 
versatile performance evaluation tool that assists researchers in 
the prediction of energy performance and optimization of various 
SSs for different engineering purposes.

\medskip

\noindent\textbf{Graphic abstract}

\bigskip

\noindent\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
Sewage sludge \sep Incintem \sep Energyce \sep Macrning \sep Optimion
\end{keyword}
        
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should revise your preamble that's full of duplications and contains several packages that are aimed to change the layout, which is something you should *not* do when submitting a paper.

Also note that `epsfig` and `latexsym` are obsolete and should not be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need to add the picture to your abstract. If so, here is the recipe:

1. You need to upload your image to you project (I use Overleaf platform for this purpose and there is a button for image uploading).
2. After this you need to put the code for your image:
   `\begin{figure}  \centering  \includegraphics{}  \caption{Caption}  \label{fig:my_label}  \end{figure}` where you'll type the picture name and its path into the `\includegraphics{}`

Regarding the graphical abstract that will represent the full contents with the one picture or transform the text into the scheme in LaTex I suggest to use Tikz

Comment: Thanks. This is the normal figure code you put. I need sth like the photo I attached. I am not sure whether there is a template or we could do like that

Comment: Thanks. And be sure that you're using the graphics library with this code : \usepackage{graphicx}